# Message: The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: ICompetitionService competitionManager

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

estou recebendo o seguinte erro em minha aplicação `Xunit`, na hora de utilizar injeção de dependência:

> Message: The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data:ICompetitionService competitionManager

Meu construtor aonde crio a injeção:

```
 private readonly CampeonatosController _campeonato;

    private readonly ICompetitionService _competitionManager;

    public CampeonatoTest(
        ICompetitionService competitionManager)
    {
        _competitionManager = competitionManager;

        _campeonato = new CampeonatosController(_competitionManager);
    }
```

Comment: esse código não diz muito, precisa ver onde vc registrou a dependência de `ICompetitionService`, se é uma classe que realmente implementa a interface

Comment: Sim isso está correto, ela implementa corretamente.

Comment: então pode colocar aqui o seu código de teste? como disse, esse código não diz muito, precisa ver o código que faz a injeção e o teste, se o mock está correto